# Typo3 Command error: Tag "var" does not exist

Tags: typo3

When running a commandcontroller through a scheduler I am getting the following failed message:

```
Tag "var" does not exist
```

...The only "var" reference is the @var comments. I've gone through each of those and they all reference variables correctly.

Does anybody know what this error might be referring to?

The entire error from the scheduler was as follows:

```
[scheduler]: scheduler - Task failed to execute successfully. Class: TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Scheduler\Task, UID: 2, Code: 1169128255, Tag "var" does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1):

For anybody else who comes across this issue, the problem was as follows:

I was using @inject for one of my protected class variables, like so:

```
* @var \Softcon\KhsjMitarbeiter\Controller\MitarbeiterController
* @inject
```

...I then added my other variables @vars BELOW this, like so

```
*  @var string $email                 
*  @var string $csvPath                
*  @var string $tableName
```

...which seemed to cause the error. I simply moved these other variable comments/tags/whatever you want to call them ABOVE the injection lines, which solved the problem.